# Problema visualizando datos de apiREST

Tags: php, sql, angular, api, rest

Muy buenas. Les comento mi problema:

Tengo un proyecto Angular, es un blog. Mi base de datos es SQL, y para poder vincular SQL a Angular cree un apiREST y quedó perfecto.

Ahora en mi proyecto puedo visualizar mis artículos traídos desde la base de datos, todo excelente. El problema es que esto solo me funciona en mi PC.

Uso ngrok para probar mis proyectos en móvil y para enviárselo a otros para que vean que tal va el proyecto. En mi PC veo mi sitio web completo, pero en otros dispositivos no me devuelve nada de mi api.

Estuve leyendo bastante sobre Access Control Allow y lo configure para que admita todos los orígenes pero nada.
Les agradezco si me explican a qué se debe esto!

Comment: Te va a funcionar siempre y cuando tu API sea accesible desde internet, es decir, que si tu mantienes tu proyecto en tu PC lo podras ver en tu red local, tus dispositivos en tu LAN, el Access Control Allow permite que cualquiera se conecte a tu API siempre y cuando tu servidor sea accesible desde internet. Por lo que te recomiendo investigues sobre la publicacion de tu API en un servidor Web.

Comment: Esto podría funcionar si incluyo el API junto a los archivos de mi proyecto? De esta manera cuando publique mi sitio en internet, el API estaría incluído en el proyecto. O se acostumbra a tenerlos separados?

Comment: Si, lo ideal es que despliegues todo tu proyecto en un mismo servidor web. Heroku es muy buena opcion y se apega a tus necesidades.